# Can I disable vaadin flow theeming and apply ordinary css

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, theming

Vaadin flow theming and styles confuse me. Is there a way to disable it and apply natural css. I know how to reference a css file inside vaadin, and use setClassName but I would prefer to use ordinary css style for components.

Thank you

Comment: When you create an index.css page and link it to your main file, I think you can use it by giving !important there.

Comment: I think it would be healthier if you specify whether you are writing the ui with java or typescript.

Comment: I am writing the ui using java

Comment: Better question; what is confusing you?

Comment: For example it confuses me the fact that I need ordinary styles of textboxes, comboboxes and date pickers. Moreover I don't know how to set colors for dynamically disabled buttons. Generally speaking someone can find a lot of info about css in the web rather than specifically for vaadin flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the default lumo styling by providing yours. For instance, to remove the background color from a ComboBox, I can target the input as follows in a CSS file named `vaadin-combo-box.css`:

```
[part="input-field"] {
    background-color: var(--lumo-base-color);
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

To set the colors for a disabled button, you can target it as follows:

filename: `vaadin-button.css`
code:

```
:host([theme~='primary'][disabled]) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And you get the following:
[image]

To change the primary color or any other global styling, explore your `styles.css` file.

For a better understanding, take a look at this video https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-theming

Answer (score 0):

Like with all other styling you need to check the states / attributes of the component while the specific state is active and check the DOM - only caveat would be that you need to add those style in the specific files like vaadin-button.css to be applied inside the shadow DOM.